# PYTHON - MULTITHREADING USING CLASSES

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, race-condition, gil

I am a absolute beginner in python multi threading. My application needs to telnet around 200 servers, execute commands and return the response. I have created separate classes for telnetting and processing the response. I read about GIL and race conditions in threading but not sure whether they will have impact in my code. Because for every thread i am creating a new instance of the class and accessing the method. So technically the threads will not share same resource. Can anyone please explain whether my assumption is right if not please explain the right way of doing it ?

## Main method :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    thread_list = []


    for ip in server_list: # server list contains the IP of hosts

         config_object = Configuration () # configuration class has method for telnet device
         thread1 = threading.Thread(target=config_object.captureconfigprocess, args=(ip))
         thread_list.append(thread1)

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I read about GIL and race conditions in threading but not sure whether they will have impact in my code

Python does not have real threads. OS will see all python threads as one process and that will require CPU to context switch between instructions sent by python. This will cripple the performance of your code. Although python threads will be more than enough for most of the case, it may or may not be enough for your case. 200 servers may seem too much but it all boils down to how much communication happens between those 200 servers and your python client. To be sure, you have to try. If you want a better solution, use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html).

> So technically the threads will not share same resource.

If each thread is using it's own resourse than shared resourse is not an issue to worry about.